# How to delete and return the last item in a linked list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, nodes

My home work needs me to pop the last item from the linked list and for some reason, some test cases works but some did not and I don't know why.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, init_data):
        self.data = init_data
        self.next = None
    def get_data(self):
        return self.data
    def get_next(self):
        return self.next
    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data
    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next = new_next
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def add(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node

    def __str__(self):
        result = "("
        node = self.head
        if node != None:
            result += str(node.data)
            node = node.next
            while node:
                result += ", " + str(node.data)
                node = node.next
        result += ")"
        return result
    def remove_from_tail(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return None
        prev = None
        cur = self.head
        while cur.next is not None:
            prev = cur
            cur = cur.next
        if prev:
            prev.next = None
        return cur

#test case one is incorrect
my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.add(400)
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
my_list.add(300)
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
my_list.add(200)
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
my_list.add(100)
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
#should be 400 300 200 100 but instead I got 400 400 300 200

#test case two works fine
fruit = LinkedList()
fruit.add('cherry')
fruit.add('banana')
fruit.add('apple')
last_one = fruit.remove_from_tail()
print('Removed:', last_one)#got"Removed: cherry"
print(fruit)#(apple, banana)
```

I don't know what is the reason for test case one to fail when `cur = self.head` and `self.head` should point to 300 after 400 is removed. So when I return cur it shouldn't print out two 400. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, the problem is that you are calling `remove_from_tail` after every add, but what you want to do is call `add` till you add all elements, and then call `remove_from_tail` one by one, which works fine

```
my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.add(400)
my_list.add(300)
my_list.add(200)
my_list.add(100)
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
```

This outputs

```
400
300
200
100
```

Also your `add` function is a little odd, generally we fix the head and for every new element, traverse to the end of the list and append it, but in your `add` you are updating every element on `head` and updating head.

Whereas your `remove_from_tail` assumes that the head is fixed and we are traversing till the end and then updating, which actually happens

So after you run add 4 times, the list is

```
head
100 -> 200 -> 300 -> 400
```

And as you expect, the tail is removed accordingly,from `400` to `100`

Also in your `remove_from_tail` function, you need to take care of the case where only one element remains in the list, and you want to remove it, once you add that your original test case works too

```
def remove_from_tail(self):
    #If linked list is empty return None
    if self.head is None:
        return None
    #If only one element in list, return that element and set head to None
    elif self.head.next is None:
        cur = self.head
        self.head = None
        return cur

    #Otherwise iterate through the list
    prev = None
    cur = self.head
    while cur.next is not None:
        prev = cur
        cur = cur.next
    if prev:
        prev.next = None
    return cur
```

The original test case then prints

```
400
300
200
100
```

as well

Comment: Because the add function needs me to add every new element at the front of the linked list that's why self.head is not fixed. Also, is there any way that the code still prints the correct answer without changing the test case??

Comment: Generally `add` adds to the last element not the front, is there a special case for you @Victoriavv okay let me update my answer to take care of that too

Comment: Cool! Check my updated answer! You missed considering one case in your function @Victoriavv